# Access denied SSH from windows to linux via putty

Tags: linux, ssh, windows, opensuse, putty

I have a fresh install of openSUSE (tumbleweed) that I am trying to access via ssh from my Windows 7 box on my local home network.  I can ping the boxes from each other successfully.  I have edited the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file on the openSUSE box and changed the port to 2223.  I have added the line AllowUsers (mylogin) to ssh_config.  PermitRootLogin is set to no.  PasswordAuthentication is set to yes.  I generated a public key on my windows machine and copied it to the openSUSE machine via a flash drive and added it to my .ssh/authorized_keys, but my understanding is this shouldn't be needed if  I have PasswordAuthentication set to yes.

I have done these things after researching different solutions on the internet but I can't seem to find a solution to my problem:  I can't login to my openSUSE box from Windows via Putty.  I can connect to a session but I get 'Access Denied' everytime I attempt a login.

edit* I can login via ssh on my linux box from my linux box using

```
ssh openSUSEcomputername -p 2223
```

Comment: Firewall/Apparmor problem?  and/or windows firewall problem?

Comment: Is something like iptables enabled by default while installing suse ?

Comment: from windows, open up a command prompt and try running `telnet suselinuxservername 2223` what do you see ?

Comment: @MelBurslan  the response to telnet is  a blank screen that says SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2 and has a blinking cursor on the next line.  If I don't type anything I get Connection to host lost after a couple minutes.

Comment: Then you don't have a firewall problem. Try shutting down sshd and starting in debug mode for one single instance with `sshd -p 2223 -D -ddd -e` and try logging in from your windows machine, while watching the log screen on your linux box. It may give you the indication why it is giving access denied message.

Comment: @MelBurslan I tried that command and I get the response 'sshd re-exec requires execution with an absolute path'.  I am not sure what that means.  I looked it up and I didn't find an answer that makes sense to me.  Can you elaborate on what I'm not doing right or doing wrong?

Comment: find the location of your ssh executable. Probably it will be something like `/usr/sbin/sshd` and replace `sshd` portion of the command above with that absolute path

Comment: I stopped the service and started it with those parameters. I attempted a connection.  The login failed and the entry in the sshd output that stood out was 'Failed keyboard-interactive/pam for invalid user (me)@(computer) from (ipaddress) port (port) ssh2'

Comment: found another entriy.. 'PAM: User not known to the underlying authentication module for illegal user (me)@(computer) from (Ip address)'

Comment: Where exactly did you put the `AllowUsers` line? Your text says in ssh_config (client side) but AFAIK it is only valid in sshd_config (server side). In either case, have you tried removing or commenting that out, at least until you get a basic connection working?

Comment: @steeldriver I put the AllowUsers line in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.  I just verified that,  was a typo in the post.  I tried logging in before I added that line with the same results.  I added that line to see if it would resolve my issue, but it didn't.

Comment: I researched the pam configuration file a bit, i don't know how to post the info in a comment.  I also checked /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow and the user exists in those files, I don't know if other information is missing or not as I don't have experience with these files.

Comment: @MelBurslan forgot to tag you on that last update

Comment: It is the latest putty version?

Comment: ugh I knew it was something simple... when I was logging in i used (username)@(servername).  after disabling PAM and testing connection I found that the login attempt was automatically appending the servername to the end of the login I entered, giving the wrong login.  i logged in using just the username and was successful.  renabled UsePAM parameter and was successful.. solved. thanks to all that responded!!

Answer (score 1):

ugh I knew it was something simple... when I was logging in i used (username)@(servername).  after disabling UsePAM and testing connection I found that the login attempt was automatically appending the servername to the end of the login I entered, giving the wrong login.  i logged in using just the username and was successful.  renabled UsePAM parameter and was successful.. solved. thanks to all that responded!!